# How should I bind to an element's style in an angular directive?

Tags: data-binding, angularjs, styles, bind, directive

I would like to bind to an absolutely positioned element's `top` style in a directive. Is this possible?

Here is what I would like to do **in made up code**:

```
angular.module('exampleModule').directive('resize', [function () {

    return {

      link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {

        var top = 14;

        // There is no styleChange event
        iElement.bind('styleChange', styleChangeHandler);

        function styleChangeHandler(event) {
          if(event.style == 'top' && event.value != top) {
            scope.$apply(function(scope){
              scope[iAttrs.topChanged](event.value);
             });
          }
        }
      }
    }

}]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no style change events. If you are in control of the style changing you can create your custom event and trigger this manually. Or you could create a watch function, something like this:

```js
link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
  //...
  scope.$watch(function(){
    return iElement.css('top');
  },styleChangeFn,true);

  function styleChangeFn(value,old){
    if(value !== old)
      scope[iAttrs.topChanged](value);
  }
}
```

Comment: This won't work because styleChangeFn is outside of the scope, but thanks. This has put me on the right track.

Comment: I assumed that `styleChangeFn` would be declared inside the link function and has access to the scope, made an update to clarify

Comment: The problem is that `scope` is not available in `styleChangeFn`.

Comment: @Pedr since the `styleChangeFn` is defined inside the link function, the scope is available inside `styleChangeFn`.

Comment: That's what I would have thought, but the scope seems to be changed. The following works as the callback (If you declare `var self = this;` before): `function(newValue, oldValue){ testFunction.call(self, newValue, oldValue)}`. Maybe I'm doing something strange ...

Comment: @joakimbl Ah. Ignore me. Appologies.

Answer (score 0):

So here is what I came up with (greatly helped by joakimbl's answer). It will work for watching any style.

The directive:

```
angular.module('unwalked.directives').directive('watchStyle', [function () {

  return {

    link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {

      scope.$watch(function(){
        return iElement.css(iAttrs['watchedStyle']);
      },
      styleChanged,
      true);

      function styleChanged(newValue, oldValue) {
        if(newValue !== oldValue) {
          scope[iAttrs['watchStyle']](newValue);
        }
      }

    }
  };

}]);
```

Usage (Note: no brackets on the callback - it's just the function name):

```
<div watch-style="functionOnController" watched-style="height" >
```